# iOS crash while executing Swift libs

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I am experiencing a peculiar series of crashes on a Target also happening on other devices for different targets. When I try to symbolicate it I am sent astray at random code locations: this is the top portion of the Binary Image at crash time:

> Binary Images:    0x73000 -   0x3cafff +inArrivo Express armv7
>   /var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/inArrivo Express   0x6b9000 -   0x820fff 
>   libswiftCore.dylib armv7
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib   0x995000 -   0x99cfff 
>   libswiftCoreAudio.dylib armv7
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreAudio.dylib   0x9ab000 -   0x9b6fff
>   libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib armv7  <95229d09c03d3eba9fbb038741503af3>
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreGraphics.dylib   0x9cd000 -
>   0x9d4fff  libswiftCoreImage.dylib armv7 
>   <59ca6e9173993aa39882799efdafd355>
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftCoreImage.dylib   0x9e4000 -   0x9ebfff
>   libswiftDarwin.dylib armv7  <764c0e157b49314088a4c9f8e1390a1a>
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftDarwin.dylib   0x9fc000 -   0x9fffff 
>   libswiftDispatch.dylib armv7
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftDispatch.dylib   0xa0e000 -   0xa3dfff 
>   libswiftFoundation.dylib armv7
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib   0xa78000 -
>   0xa7ffff  libswiftObjectiveC.dylib armv7 
>   <786938b80ba63395aa5da6935df0c02e>
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftObjectiveC.dylib   0xa8c000 -
>   0xa8ffff  libswiftSecurity.dylib armv7 
>   <12a8743e1ad636ebaaac523d1d709341>
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftSecurity.dylib   0xa9a000 -   0xaa5fff 
>   libswiftUIKit.dylib armv7
>   /private/var/mobile/Applications/D2AE6804-C6CC-4953-AB14-1C5439420D0F/inArrivo
>   Express.app/Frameworks/libswiftUIKit.dylib

while the crash happens in this frame:

```
1   CoreFoundation                      0x2f481167 0x2f3e2000 + 651623
2   CoreFoundation                      0x2f480d7f 0x2f3e2000 + 650623
3   CoreFoundation                      0x2f47f11b 0x2f3e2000 + 643355
4   CoreFoundation                      0x2f3e9ebf 0x2f3e2000 + 32447
5   CoreFoundation                      0x2f3e9ca3 0x2f3e2000 + 31907
6   GraphicsServices                    0x342ef663 0x342e6000 + 38499
7   UIKit                               0x31d3614d 0x31cc8000 + 450893
8   inArrivo Express                    0x0007dc5d 0x73000 + 44125 
9   libdyld.dylib                       0x3a173ab7 0x3a172000 + 6839
```

Tracing the program is nearly worthless as the crash happens really at random times. What could it be?

The Xcode crash report was a bit more precise than the QuincyKit one and invariantly reports:

```
__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION as in:
```

> Thread 0: 0   ???                             0000000000 0 + 0 1
>   CoreFoundation                    0x2f481166
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 14 2   CoreFoundation                 0x2f480d7e __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 782 3
>   CoreFoundation                    0x2f47f11a __CFRunLoopRun + 1210 4
>   CoreFoundation                    0x2f3e9ebe CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522 5
>   CoreFoundation                    0x2f3e9ca2 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106 6
>   GraphicsServices                  0x342ef662 GSEventRunModal + 138 7
>   UIKit                             0x31d3614c UIApplicationMain + 1136 8
>   inArrivo Express                  0x000dbbdc 0xd1000 + 43996 9
>   libdyld.dylib                     0x3a173ab6 start + 2
>
> Thread 1 Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a216808
>   kevent64 + 24 1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a162de8
>   _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228 2   libdispatch.dylib              0x3a151f6e _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 34

on the thread of my app, even if the crash happened on another thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crash seemed due to calling a new datatask on a session before the previous one was terminated. I came to that by trial an error by trying and removing all code specific for the target. Apple said crashes happened closer to the problem in Swift, respect to Objective-c, but it seems to be returning to the time of the C dangling pointers! That is where 90's computer science and php programming experience come to the fore! Please Apple take note Swift should be a 21 century language for the next 20 years and the runtime support should be consequent.